# How to obtain the path of a library

Tags: g++

I can compile my executable file by follow commands

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ main.o -o my_exe -lmy
```

I do not need to specify the path of the `libmy.a` using `-L path` during link.

The `libmy.a` can automatically find by system.

Now I want to find the path of `libmy.a` but I have no idea where it is.

How can I obtain the full path of `libmy.a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:-

```
g++ main.o -o my_exe -lmy
```

link your program with:-

```
g++ main.o -o my_exe -lmy -Wl,-trace
```

This will make `g++` pass the diagnostic option [`-trace`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) to the [linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/). The linker
will print the pathname by which it locates every object file, shared library or static libary that it inputs. Inspect the output and you will find the full pathname of `libmy.a`

Comment: What a fantastic way! now I can have the better understand what happen during the link!